# declare php variable, isset? not isset?

Tags: php, html, forms

So here is my code:

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $tall1 = $_POST['tall1'];

        echo '<script>alert("hello!");</script>'; 

    }
?>
<div id="div1">
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input class="form" id="tall1" name"tall1">
    <select class="form" name="type">
        <option>+</option>
        <option>-</option>
        <option>*</option>
        <option>/</option>
    </select>
    <select class="form" name="color">
        <option>white</option>
        <option>black</option>
        <option>red</option>
        <option>green</option>
    </select>
    <input class="form" id="tall2" name"tall2">
    <input type="submit" class="form"  name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
```

This gives me this error: Notice: Undefined index: tall1 in C:\blabla\index.php on line 34
, But i do get an echo...
and if i do like this:

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['tall1'])){
        $tall1 = $_POST['tall1'];

        echo '<script>alert("hello!");</script>'; 

    }
?>
```

It doesn't echo at all like it isn't working.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot a `=` in your HTML, so your browser doesn't send data for the `tall1` field:

```
<input class="form" id="tall1" name="tall1">
                                   ^ here

<input class="form" id="tall2" name="tall2">
                                   ^ here too
```

The form was submitted indeed, so `$_POST['submit']` existed (created by your submit button, well written), but not the `tall1` key :-)

Comment: ofc a typo, thanks :)

Comment: +1: You did get your answer in a few seconds before I did, and you explained about the form submission process

Comment: Eheh, S.O is often a keyboard typing race, unfortunately for you this time.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a typo; you're missing an equals sign, which is forming invalid HTML.

```
<input class="form" id="tall1" name"tall1">
                                   ^ missing an equals sign

<input class="form" id="tall1" name="tall1">
...
<input class="form" id="tall1" name="tall2">
```

As a note, both of those inputs are missing a type and a value. Perhaps [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) will be of service?

Comment: ofc a typo, thanks :)

Comment: The default type on an input is text.

Comment: @ElefantPhace - Correct. He also doesn't need to define a value within the input tags. However, I'd argue that including both (even if it ends up being `type="text"` and `value=""`) adds clarity to how the element is being used.